# Explanation regarding "if(td)" after for loop

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm learning how to build a filtered list or table from w3schools.
I understood most of the code except those pasted below:
Reference link to w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp

Question: What does "if(td)" means?

For reasons unknown to me "td.textContent" doesn't seem to work without the "if(td)" which w3school recommends. So I need help to understand this.

```js
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {            
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That means if `td` is not false or in other words `if` td is not `null` so instead of `if(td!=null)`  you can use `if(td)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
```

With that line, it is trying to get first TD in current iterated TR, and with line

```
if (td) {
```

it checks if there is a TD matched and can work on that like

```
  txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
```

otherwise that lines can cause error like
"td is not defined"

if there is no match for TD, it iterates next value of "i" in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a simple console.log() before the if statment, you will understand the cause.

In fact, td can be empty or `undefined`. The **first td** is undefined.

```
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    console.log('td =>', td)
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
```

Wil output:

```
td => undefined
td => <td>
```

In your case, td can be undefined simply beacause the **tr** (`tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];`) doesnt contain any td !